# Surfaceplot Heightcolors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtgraph

I am doing a animated surface plot via tcp-data.

When the data incoming are small (random 0 - 5) i get a nicely colored Graph, but when i send bigger data (e.g. -50 to +50) the colors get messed up (pictures below), where the whole surface graph is white. I've tried some matplotlib Colormaps, but the result was similiar, with only the white changing to another color, but no surface was visible due to everything having the same color.

Heres my code:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np
import datetime
from matplotlib import cm

numberOfData = 1000
widthOfData = 500
x = np.linspace(-widthOfData / 2, widthOfData / 2, widthOfData)
y = np.linspace(-numberOfData / 2, numberOfData / 2, numberOfData)
#colormap = cm.get_cmap('jet')  # cm.get_cmap("CMRmap") 'viridis'
#colormap._init()
#lut = (colormap._lut * 255).view(np.ndarray)  # Convert matplotlib colormap from 0-1 to 0 -255 for Qt
p4 = gl.GLSurfacePlotItem(x, y, shader='heightColor', computeNormals=False,
                          smooth=False)  # smooth true = faster; dont turn on computenormals
p4.shader()['colorMap'] = np.array([0.2, 2, 0.5, 0.2, 1, 1, 0.2, 0, 2]) #lut
# p4.setGLOptions('opaque')
data = np.zeros((widthOfData, numberOfData), dtype=int)

index = 0


def init():
    global p4, data, index

    ## Create a GL View widget to display data
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = gl.GLViewWidget()
    w.show()
    w.setWindowTitle('PAS Surfaceplot')
    w.setGeometry(100, 100, 1500, 800)  # distance && resolution
    w.setCameraPosition(distance=1000)

    ## Create axis
    # axis = pg.AxisItem('left', pen=None, linkView=None, parent=None, maxTickLength=-5, showValues=True)
    # axis.show()
    # axis = pg.AxisItem('left', pen = None)
    # xAxis.paint()
    # Axis.setSize(self.valueNumber, self.valueNumber, self.valueNumber)
    # axis.setStyle(showValues = True)
    # axis.show()
    # --------------------
    axis = gl.GLAxisItem()
    # xAxis.paint()
    # axis.setSize(self.valueNumber, self.valueNumber, self.valueNumber)
    w.addItem(axis)

    ## Add a grid to the view
    g = gl.GLGridItem()
    g.setSize(x=widthOfData * 2, y=numberOfData * 2)
    # g.scale(2,2,1000)
    g.setDepthValue(10)  # draw grid after surfaces since they may be translucent
    w.addItem(g)

    ## create a surface plot, tell it to use the 'heightColor' shader
    ## since this does not require normal vectors to render (thus we
    ## can set computeNormals=False to save time when the mesh updates)
    # p4.translate(100, 100, 0)
    w.addItem(p4)

    # timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    # timer.timeout.connect(updateSelf)
    # timer.start(20)

    ## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

#update via timer
def updateSelf():
    global p4, data, index
    timeBeforeUpdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    data = np.delete(data, 0, 0)
    newValues = np.random.randint(5, size=(1, numberOfData))
    # print('newval ', newValues)
    data = np.concatenate((data, newValues))
    p4.setData(z=data)
    timeAfterUpdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeDiff = timeAfterUpdate - timeBeforeUpdate
    elapsed_ms = (timeDiff.days * 86400000) + (timeDiff.seconds * 1000) + (timeDiff.microseconds / 1000)
    # print(elapsed_ms, ' ms')

#update via tcp
def update(framesList):
    global p4, data, index
    timeBeforeUpdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    for frame in framesList:
        data = np.delete(data, 0, 0)
        frame = np.array(frame, ndmin=2)
        # print('data: ', data)
        # print('frame: ', frame)
        data = np.concatenate((data, frame))
        p4.setData(z=data)
    timeAfterUpdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeDiff = timeAfterUpdate - timeBeforeUpdate
    elapsed_ms = (timeDiff.days * 86400000) + (timeDiff.seconds * 1000) + (timeDiff.microseconds / 1000)
    print(elapsed_ms, ' ms')

# init()
# timer = QtCore.QTimer()
# timer.timeout.connect(updateSelf)
# timer.start(20)
```

How do i fix this?

working colors

[image]

messed up colors

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved the issue with

```
self.surfacePlot.shader()['colorMap'] = np.array([0.01, 40, 0.5, 0.01, 40, 1, 0.01, 40, 2])  # lut
```

The problem was indeed that the color brightens way too fast.

Colormaps are defined by 3 triples, where index_0^index_3 determines the color. So in my case it is now 0.01^0.5, 0.01^1 and 0.01^2.
Sadly i can't find the wiki-code example where i found this in a comment

Answer (score 0):

From what I can think of, the unified color is because of high density of the data. Since the variation occurs as you increase your data, what you can try is reducing the range of data, i.e. for -50 to 50, try dividing it first by 10, so as to get the values in range of -10 to 10. That should help.

Comment: Hey Nitin, scaling down the data works, but is not really the solution i've been looking for. I don't think the density or size of the data is the reason, since the problem still remains when sending a lot less data. I think the problem has to be related to some sort of interval, since the surface has colors at the bottom, but turns white afterwards like for example: https://imgur.com/1mjJARE

Comment: The image shows that the color lightens till a point and then goes absolutely bright. Can you try increasing Depth Value from 10? I think it might be causing this behaviour.

Comment: The g.setDepthValue(10) is only for the grid, right? I tried increasing it just now, and also added p4.setDepthValue(1000). Sadly both didn't solve the problem